# Webscraping with VBA morningstar financial

Tags: regex, vba, excel, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to scrape the inside ownership from Morningstar at this url: 
http://investors.morningstar.com/ownership/shareholders-overview.html?t=TWTR&region=usa&culture=en-US

This is the code I'm using:

```
Sub test()

    Dim appIE As Object

    Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With appIE
        .Navigate "http://investors.morningstar.com/ownership/shareholders-overview.html?t=TWTR&region=usa&culture=en-US"
        .Visible = True
    End With
    While appIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Set allRowOfData = appIE.Document.getElementById("currentInsiderVal")
    Debug.Print allRowOfData
    Dim myValue As String: myValue = allRowOfData.Cells(0).innerHTML
    appIE.Quit
    Set appIE = Nothing

    Range("A30").Value = myValue

End Sub
```

I get run-time error 13 at line

```
Set allRowOfData = appIE.Document.getElementById("currentInsiderVal")
```

but I can't see any mismatch. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do it with XHR and RegEx instead of cumbersome IE:

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim sContent
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://investors.morningstar.com/ownership/shareholders-overview.html?t=TWTR&region=usa&culture=en-US", False
        .Send
        sContent = .ResponseText
    End With
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = ",""currInsiderVal"":(.*?),"
        Range("A30").Value = .Execute(sContent).Item(0).SubMatches(0)
    End With
End Sub
```

**Here is the description how the code works:**

First of all `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` ActiveX instance is created. GET request opened with target URL in synchronous mode (execution interrupts until response received).

Then `VBScript.RegExp` is created. By default `.IgnoreCase`, `.Global` and `.MultiLine` properties are `False`. The pattern is `,"currInsiderVal":(.*?),`, where `(.*?)` is a capturing group, `.` means any character, `.*` - zero or more characters, `.*?` - as few as possible characters (lazy matching). Other characters in pattern to be found as is. `.Execute` method returns a collection of matches, there is only one match object in it since `.Global` is `False`. This match object has a collection of submatches, there is only one submatch in it since the pattern contains the only capturing group.
There are some helpful MSDN articles on regex:
[Microsoft Beefs Up VBScript with Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx)
[Introduction to Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2(v=vs.84).aspx)

**Here is the description how I created the code:**

First I found an element containing the target value on the webpage DOM using browser:

[image: target value]

The corresponding node is:

```html
<td align="right" id="currrentInsiderVal">143.51</td>
```

Then I made XHR and found this node in the response HTML, but it didn't contain the value (you can find response in the browser developer tools on network tab after you refresh the page):

```html
<td align="right" id="currrentInsiderVal">
</td>
```

Such behavior is typical for DHTML. Dynamic HTML content is generated by scripts after the webpage loaded, either after retrieving a data from web via XHR or just processing already loaded withing webpage data. Then I just searched for the value `143.51` in the response, the snippet `,"currInsiderVal":143.51,` located within JS function:

```
            fundsArr = {"fundTotalHistVal":132.61,"mutualFunds":[[1,89,"#a71620"],[2,145,"#a71620"],[3,152,"#a71620"],[4,198,"#a71620"],[5,155,"#a71620"],[6,146,"#a71620"],[7,146,"#a71620"],[8,132,"#a71620"]],"insiderHisMaxVal":3.535,"institutions":[[1,273,"#283862"],[2,318,"#283862"],[3,351,"#283862"],[4,369,"#283862"],[5,311,"#283862"],[6,298,"#283862"],[7,274,"#283862"],[8,263,"#283862"]],"currFundData":[2,2202,"#a6001d"],"currInstData":[1,4370,"#283864"],"instHistMaxVal":369,"insiders":[[5,0.042,"#ff6c21"],[6,0.057,"#ff6c21"],[7,0.057,"#ff6c21"],[8,3.535,"#ff6c21"],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0]],"currMax":4370,"histLineQuars":[[1,"Q2"],[2,"Q3"],[3,"Q4"],[4,"Q1<br>2015"],[5,"Q2"],[6,"Q3"],[7,"Q4"],[8,"Q1<br>2016"]],"fundHisMaxVal":198,"currInsiderData":[3,143,"#ff6900"],"currFundVal":2202.85,"quarters":[[1,"Q2"],[2,""],[3,""],[4,"Q1<br>2015"],[5,""],[6,""],[7,""],[8,"Q1<br>2016"]],"insiderTotalHistVal":3.54,"currInstVal":4370.46,"currInsiderVal":143.51,"use10YearData":"false","instTotalHistVal":263.74,"maxValue":369};
```

So the regex pattern created based on that it should find the snippet `,"currInsiderVal":<some text>,` where `<some text>` is our target value.

Comment: You're an absolute legend, I've spent days trying to do this. Instead of me using this mindlessly, could you explain one or two things? Such as the second with.. you've used currInsiderVal instead of currrentInsiderVal.. does that mean look for words that have those characters so I would have to make sure what I'm looking for is unique? and does the item(0) look for the first item (what does item in this case actually mean?) then submatch(0) looks for the first element in the item?? Many many thanks for your help!!

Comment: @AidanO'Farrell take a look at the description I added.

Answer (score 0):

Had a look on the site and the element you are trying to retrieve has a typo in it; instead of `currentInsiderVal` try using `currrentInsiderVal` and you should retrieve the data correctly.

Probably worth considering some error trapping to catch stuff like this for any other fields you retrieve?

After your comment I took a closer look.  Your issue seemed like it was trying to trap the id of the individual cell rather than navigating down the object tree.  I've modified the code to retrieve the row of the table you are after and then set myValue to be the correct cell within that row.  Seemed to be working when I tried it out.  Give this a shot?

```
Sub test()

Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")


With appIE
    .Navigate "http://investors.morningstar.com/ownership/shareholders-overview.html?t=TWTR&region=usa&culture=en-US"
    .Visible = True
End With

While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

Set allRowOfData = appIE.Document.getelementbyID("tableTest").getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(5)
myValue = allRowOfData.Cells(2).innerHTML

appIE.Quit
Set appIE = Nothing
Range("A30").Value = myValue
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh Thanks! I'm hoping you can help me again (sorry - new to vba as I said). So once I corrected that mistake, I still get the same runtime error 013.. so I removed the 'set' then it runs through to where I define myValue at which point I get runtime error 424, saying I need to use 'set' (note when I do this the debug.print gives a value of null). So then I use set again and of course I get the same error. I obviously don't understand html structure and tried to use innerText instead of innerHTML but I still get the same problem... anything else you can think of that I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: Cheers dave, I think that works - I mean all it seems to do is increase the height of the cell, doesn't seem to contain anything as there are no words/text in the cell or text line although it appears something might be in there but its invisible - as silly as it sounds there is something in there I can highlight and I tried to change the colour (just incase it was set to white) but that didn't work. I'll have a look at it more tomorrow. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Sounds like you might be picking up an empty cell rather than the one with a value.  I ran the code above locally in Excel and it happily pulled back the 141.9 (or whatever it was) value...  Open the webpage, and inspect the element you want to retrieve with Developer Tools in IE (F12).  On the DOM Explorer, the heirarchy to your element is listed at the bottom.  Working from the parent table object, follow the path down to the element you want...

Comment: I've had a quick look again and it still gives me the same issue. Maybe what you posted wasn't exactly the code you have - theres a typo in the getelementsbyID so maybe there is another typo above. But, you've given me enough to get on with as it is so I'll try to resolve it and hopefully i wont need to ask for your help again!

Comment: Just an update - all of a sudden its works. I have no idea what the problem was before... i literally reran and it worked. Thanks so much!